# How to call back checkboxs in kivy?

Tags: python, function, checkbox, radio-button, kivy

```
    self.t_and_c = Label(text='Accept terms and conditions: ')
    self.inside.add_widget(self.t_and_c)
   
    self.checkbox_first = CheckBox(active=False)
    self.checkbox_first.bind(active = self.checkbox_status)
    self.inside.add_widget(self.checkbox_first)
    
    self.pvt_policy = Label(text='Accept private policy: ')
    self.inside.add_widget(self.pvt_policy)
    
    self.checkbox_second = CheckBox(active=False)
    self.checkbox_second.bind(active = self.checkbox_status)
    
    self.inside.add_widget(self.checkbox_second)
    self.inside.add_widget(Label())
    self.enter = Button(text='Enter information', disabled=True)
    self.inside.add_widget(self.enter)
    
    
def checkbox_status(self, instance):
    if self.checkbox_first.active == True and self.checkbox_second.active == True:
        self.enter.disabled == False
    else:
        self.enter.disabled == True
```

I want to create a function which disables a button until two checkboxes have been 'checked'. I am trying to call the checkbox but I get this error:

```
TypeError: checkbox_status() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I am confused as to why I would need another input argument, any help is appreciated but please could the answer be given in the Python language rather than `kv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback for binding to the `active` property of a `Checkbox` expects to call that callback with two arguments, the `CheckBox` instance and the new value of the `active` property. Since the `checkbox_status()` method you are specifying in:

```
self.checkbox_second.bind(active = self.checkbox_status)
```

is an instance method of class (note the `self.`) a `self` argument is automatically inserted as the first argument to the method call. This results in an argument list for the `checkbox_status()` method as:

```
checkbox_status(self, checkbox_instance, new_value)
```

So the signature of the method should be:

```
def checkbox_status(self, instance, new_value):
```

or

```
def checkbox_status(self, instance, *args):
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, i ran this and when i check both boxes the button still stays disabled and there is no error is there any reason for this?

Comment: In your `checkbox_status()` method you are using `==` in places where you should use `=`.